# How to update only one column of sql table by csv file

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a csv file containg some data. And in my Sql Database I have a table with multiple column name. Now I want to update only one column by csv file.
Thanks

Comment: make your question a bit more clear. either you want to dump the data from csv file into mysql or any other.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
-Import the csv file to a temp table
-Update your main table by joining with a temp table.
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) you can do this

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'mycsvdata.csv'
INTO TABLE mytable
( @csvfield1, @csvfield2 )
SET myTabField = @csvfield2;
```