# Single column CSV to two column MySql table data store

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, csv

I have a csv file which contains 2000 data in one single column. The data format is like following:

```
name 100/1
name 100/2
name 105/6 
 ...
```

So the general format is 'text integer_one/integer_two' Now I want it to store in a mysql database table with 2 columns.  column_1 should have the data integer_one, and column_2 should have the data integer_two

How can I do this using php to push the data into mysql?

Comment: MySQL can import CSV directly and also has RegEx functions. It can be handled completely by MySQL. As a starting point => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512209/how-to-update-only-one-column-of-sql-table-by-csv-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First start by extracting your values. If all your data is formated like in your example, you can use a simple `explode`.

```
$lines = explode(",", $data); // $data should be your file extracted into a string
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $temp = explode(" ", $line);
    $name = $temp[0];
    $temp_2 = explode("/", $temp[1]);
    $integer_1 = $temp_2[0];
    $integer_2 = $temp_2[1];

    $query = "INSERT INTO table_two_columns SET name = '{$name}', integer_1 = '{$integer_1}', integer_2 = '{$integer_2}'";
}
```

Well that's my take on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at preg_match, you should be able to get these values using a fairly trivial regular expression, like:

```
preg_match(/\w+\s*(\d+)\\\/(\d+)/, $row, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

To pull the data from a file take a look at `fgets` there are example of reading the file line-by-line to get the `$row` variable in the code above.

You can then write each line to the database using an INSERT statement.

Some things to consider:

How large is the file?
How often do you need to insert this data - is it a one-off?

These things will influence how you build your code; there are multiple ways to bulk insert data, and if this is just a one-off run then I would suggest maniuplating the text data using `sed` or similar, and then bulk inserting using the native methods of your database of choice (for mysql see `LOAD DATA INFILE`, or using the `\.` option in the client)

If the file is large and you need to insert things regularly, look at using prepared statements, and/or the multiple insert syntax:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (name, number, anothernumber) VALUES('paul', 1, 2),('bob',2,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ph function [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function to read a csv file (example is give in this page) then take each in loop and parse it using function [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and create query from it and save in database

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and [fread()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) or [fgetcsv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) php functions to handle the files, with them you should be able to loop through the lines of the cvs file, If you have control over your server configuration, I would suggest you to have a look into [SplFileObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php) instead, because you can handle the files more efficient/elegantly, and object oriented. but require you to enable SPL. This last one is my recommendation, as you could read the file like this:

```
function random_name(){
            $file_name = "names.csv";
            if(is_readable($file_name)){
                $file = new SplFileObject($file_name);


                $file->seek($file->getSize());
                $linesTotal = $file->key();

                $file->seek(rand(1,$linesTotal-1));
                $line = $file->fgetcsv();

                return $line[4];
            }
        }
```

This was a sample script of mine to get a random name from a 1000 name cvs file.

As you loop and get the file information, you can then use [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), this function separates your string by the separator you define, in your case it would be:

```
$array = explode("/", $myLine);
```

And you would access like this:

```
$array[0] or $array[1] to get the value
```